# Is it possible to avoid repetition of std::move() on a tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, stdtuple

Let's say I have a tuple and a function:

```
typedef std::tuple< std::unqiue_ptr<int>, std::unqiue_ptr<char> > SomeTuple;          
void someFunction( std::unqiue_ptr<int>, std::unqiue_ptr<char> );
```

so in a helper function I am unrolling tuple into arguments:

```
void unroll( SomeTuple &t )
{
    someFunction( std::get<0>( std::move( t ) ), std::get<1>( std::move( t ) ) );
}
```

It works, but I want to avoid repeating of `std::move` multiple times. Naive solutions like:

```
void unroll( SomeTuple &t )
{
    auto &&rt = std::move( t );
    someFunction( std::get<0>( rt ), std::get<1>( rt ) );
}
```

obviosly does not work, as rt is a `lvalue`. So is there a way to avoid repeating `std::move()` multiple times for each `std::get`?

Comment: To _really_ avoid repetition, grab one of the many "exploding tuple" implementations, which lets you just 'explode' a tuple into a matching function call's arguments. So-called thanks to (AFAIK) the grand-daddy presentation on the topic, [The Way of the Exploding Tuple](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/The-Way-of-the-Exploding-Tuple). All you need is variadic templates, but if you have C++14 you can get much simpler implementations, e.g., [Exploding Tuple in C++14](http://makecleanandmake.com/2014/10/15/exploding-tuple-in-c14/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

It is available from C++14 but can be implemented with C++11 : https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/pythran/blob/master/pythran/pythonic/include/utils/seq.hpp

Thanks to this, you need an extra function but you avoid this repetition :

```
void unroll( SomeTuple &t )
{
    someFunction( std::get<0>( std::move( t ) ), std::get<1>( std::move( t ) ) );
}
```

becomes

```
template<size_t ...I>
void unroll_impl( SomeTuple &t , std::integer_sequence<I...>)
{
    someFunction( std::get<I>( std::move( t ) )...);
}

void unroll( SomeTuple &t )
{
    unroll_impl( t, std::make_index_sequence<2>{});
}
```

But you have to create an helper function for this.

Comment: When you don't specify the type you have to use `std::make_index_sequence` (which will use `size_t` by default) rather than `std::make_integer_sequence`. And I believe you don't need either `typename` nor `::type()`.

Comment: Won't `t` still be moved multiple times after pack expansion?

Comment: @0x499602D2: it'll be passed to `std::move` multiple times, but `std::get<N>` on a `std::tuple` rvalue reference will return an rvalue reference to the N'th element. _That_ will get moved from when the `someFunction` call is evaluated in `unroll_impl`.

Simply, `std::get<I>( std::move( t ) )` is precisely equivalent to `std::move( std::get<I>( t ) )`

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, you can't avoid the `std::move`. To get an rvalue, you need to either not have a name for something (so you can't refer to it twice) or strip the name with `std::move`. And `t` has a name, but to pass a `unique_ptr` to a function call, you need it to not have a name.

You can see this for example by changing unroll to the (more idiomatic?)

```
void unroll( SomeTuple &t )
{
  someFunction( std::move( std::get<0>( t ) ), std::move( std::get<1>( t ) ) );
}
```

Any solution is going to involve either a `std::move()` on each `unique_ptr` function parameter, or a call to another function that returns an rvalue or rvalue reference.

```
void unroll( SomeTuple &t )
{
    auto get0 = [&]()->std::unique_ptr<int>&& { return std::move(std::get<0>(t)); };
    auto get1 = [&]()->std::unique_ptr<char> { return std::move(std::get<1>(t)); };

    someFunction( get0(), get1() );
}
```